# How to set up google authentication in asp.net core api

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am new to asp, On front end I have react and I want to authenticate users using external login providers. I have obtained client Id and secret from google.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(auth =>
{
    auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["AuthSettings:Key"]);
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["AuthSettings:Audience"],
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["AuthSettings:Issuer"],
        RequireExpirationTime = true, 
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
    };
}).AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
}); ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Next, you need to add two method in your controller.

To handle the external login request:

```
   /// <summary>
   /// Handle the External Login Request. 
   /// This method redirects the user to the respective provider's login page.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="provider"></param>
   /// <returns></returns>
   [AllowAnonymous]
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLogin(string provider="Google")
   {
       try
       {
           var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), "User");
           var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
           return Challenge(properties, provider);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           return StatusCode(500,ex);
       }
   }
```

Here, your provider is Google. you can use other providers such as Facebook and etc. In the above method the "User" is the name of my controller. you should replace it by your controler name. The content of the method is a page. You could put it in your front end.

and the second method:

```
   /// <summary>
   /// Handle the External Login Callback
   /// Implement a method to handle the callback from Google after a successful external login.
   /// The access token can be obtained using HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token") method
   /// within the ExternalLoginCallback method.
   /// </summary>
   /// <returns></returns>
   [AllowAnonymous]
   [HttpGet]
   public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback()
   {
       try
       {
           var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
           if (info == null)
           {
               return StatusCode(400,"Bad Request");
           }

           // Obtain the access token
           var accessToken = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

           // Access other user information if needed
           var user = info.Principal;

           // Process the success login and token as per your requirements
           return StatusCode(200, accessToken);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           return StatusCode(500, ex);
       }
   }
```

In my example the redirect url is ended by

```
/User/ExternalLoginCallback
```